# В PyQt5 обрезается Label

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel, qlayout

Есть окно, созданное с помощью *PyQt5*, в котором есть `Label`, установленный так:

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    ...
    self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50,10,10,10))
    self.label1.setObjectName("label1")
    self.label1.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 10))
    ...

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    ...
    self.label1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Website/App"))
```

При запуске программы вместо "**`Website/App`**" выводится "**`Website/`**", а если сместить `Label` правее, то текст вообще не отображается.

Загуглив, я увидел, что решение везде одно - добавить метод:

```
def update(self):
    self.label1.adjustSize()
```

и вызывать его в методе `rentranslateUi` /при нажатии некоторых кнопок/ и тд.

Решение с `adjustSize()` мне не помогло.

---

Минимальный воспроизводимый пример:

```
from sys import argv
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 250)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50,10,10,10))
        self.label1.setObjectName("label1")
        self.label1.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 10))

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Password 
Manager"))
        self.label1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Website/App"))
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.label1.adjustSize()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    uiMainWindow = Ui_MainWindow()
    uiMainWindow.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я не знаю, как поправить код, чтобы он заработал. 
Подскажите, буду очень признателен.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick обновил пост

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**НИКОГДА Не изменяйте** код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*. **НИКОГДА**!

Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Вам надо освоить менеджеры компоновки.  [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):                      # (QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 250)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50,10,10,10))
        self.label1.setObjectName("label1")
        self.label1.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 10))

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Password Manager"))
        self.label1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Website/App"))
#        self.update()

#    def update(self):
#        self.label1.adjustSize()
        
        
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    uiMainWindow = Ui_MainWindow()
#    uiMainWindow.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()
    
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]